# Is my proof correct of: If $A$ is a complete proper subspace of an inner product space $X$, then there exists a non-zero vector in $A^{\perp}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

$A$ is complete iff $A$ is closed, then we have $X = A \oplus A^{\perp}$. Suppose $A^{\perp}=\{0\}$, then $X=A$ which is a contradiction?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: @Zardo I'm not sure if $X$ can be expressed as a direct sum. Don't we need $X$ to be complete?

Comment: You don't need $X$ to be complete. The completeness of $A$ is sufficient to define an orthogonal projection $P:X\to A$. Then by $x = Px + (I-P)x$ ($I$ being the identity) you can write every element of $X$ as sum of elements of $A$ and $A^\perp$. The uniqueness follows from the properties of the projection.

Comment: You write that $A$ is complete iff $A$ is closed. That's not necessarily true if $X$ is not complete. Did you change something and then forget to update your question in that regard?

Comment: @TrialAndError If we assume A is complete then I don't think we need completeness of X to show that A is closed. At least that's what our teacher said in class at the time when we were proving that every finite dimensional subspace of a normed space X is closed in X. We assumed A is complete and then used the results "a subspace of a complete metric space is complete iff it is closed" and "every finite dimensional subspace of a normed space is complete" to show A is closed.

Comment: @TrialAndError How would you go about proving this?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is complete and $x \notin A$, then you can choose $\{ a_{n} \} \subset A$ such that $d_n=\|a_n-x\|$ converges to $d=\mbox{dist}(x,A)$. Then it follows that $\{ a_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Because $A$ is complete, then $\lim_n a_n = a$ for some $a \in A$. Furthermore, $\|a-x\|=d$. Because $a$ is the closest element of $A$ to $x$, then $x-a \perp A$.